# Android: How to send json request with variable and read json response from the webserver using POST methods?

Tags: android, json

I am new and can any body write a simple code for sending json request on the following webserver link with variable "data" and then fetch the json response, an example is also given, i am given with this information

> http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php?tag=GetDeviceInfo
>
> JSON Request (Posted in body with variable "data")
>
> {
>       "did": "1"
>   }
>
> JSON Response
>
> {
>       "status": 200,
>       "status_message": "Success",
>       "data": {
>           "did": "1",
>           "displayname": "Malik Kamran",
>           "dtoken": "sdfhskdflkasjdfklajslkdfj",
>           "dtype": "ios",
>           "dateadded": "2015-04-25 15:47:34 -0700",
>           "country": "Pakistan",
>           "continent": "Asia",
>           "lat": "123.46477",
>           "lng": "123.46477"
>       }
>   }

Comment: [Let me google that for you](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: You should probably check this site http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

It has explained in detail what to do and how to do step wise.

Answer (score 0):

Call following method from non-ui thread and pass url and body content. Use AsyncTask and call below method in doInBackground method.

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            String url  = "http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php?tag=GetDeviceInfo";
            String body = "{ \"did\": \"1\" }";

            return excutePost(url,body);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result != null){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    int status = jsonObject.getInt("status");
                    JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    String displayName = dataObject.getString("displayname");


                    //do your stuff here

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } 




public  String excutePost(String targetURL, String body)
      {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
        try {
          //Create connection
          url = new URL(targetURL);
          connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
               "application/json");

          connection.setUseCaches (false);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setDoOutput(true);

          //Send request
          DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                      connection.getOutputStream ());
          wr.writeBytes (body);
          wr.flush ();
          wr.close ();

          if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
          //Get Response    
              InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
              String line;
              StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
              while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
              }
              rd.close();
              return response.toString();
          }else{
              InputStream is = connection.getErrorStream();
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
              String line;
              StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
              while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
              }
              rd.close();
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;

        } finally {

          if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect(); 
          }
        }
      }
```

I think it help you.

Comment: sir it is giving file not found exception and input stream,

Comment: i checked by using postman it returned {
    "status": 402,
    "status_message": "Parameter is missing",
    "data": null
}

Comment: http://teespire.com/ptracking/post/index.php?tag=GetTrackerInfo

{
    "tid": "1"
}

it gives same error on this link also, will webserver respond on it,

and this webserver is working well on other devices